# Add calculateage function to Date of Birth select tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, datepicker, date

There is a popular function which calculates the person's age based on their Date of Birth if the jQuery datepicker function is used. The functions are as follows:

```
function calculateAge(birthday) {
    var mybirthday = new Date(birthday.split("-").reverse().join("-")).getTime();
    var ageDifMs = Date.now() - mybirthday; //.getTime();
    var ageDate = new Date(ageDifMs); // miliseconds from epoch
    return Math.abs(ageDate.getUTCFullYear() - 1970);
}


function dateDiffInYears(dateold, datenew) {
    var ynew = datenew.getFullYear();
    var mnew = datenew.getMonth();
    var dnew = datenew.getDate();
    var yold = dateold.getFullYear();
    var mold = dateold.getMonth();
    var dold = dateold.getDate();
    var diff = ynew - yold;
    if (mold > mnew) diff--;
    else {
        if (mold == mnew) {
            if (dold > dnew) diff--;
        }
    }
    return diff;
}


$(".datepic").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    yearRange: '-90:+0',
    onClose: function (selectedDate) {
        if (calculateAge(selectedDate) < 12) {
            $("#parent_section").show();
        } else {
            $("#parent_section").hide();
        }
    }
});
```

However,this works perfectly well where the user selects the date when they enter their cursor in the textbox and they have to select a date from the datepicker.

The problem I have is that I have three separate select tags. One for date, another for the month and another for the year. How can I get the person's age to be calculated using these select tags. I have spent a long time on this and cannot figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.